# Azure, Asp.Net and inproc session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, session-state

The azure load balancer now supports session affinity, does this mean inproc sessions are now possible or is redis cache still the only alternative?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-load-balancer-new-distribution-mode/

(edit). There are two aspects to this question

(1) If you have a legacy product you want to migrate that depends on inproc sessions can they be migrated

(2) 'session affinity' on the load balancer, does that help at all here

Comment: Redis cache was never the only alternative, as there are lots of ways to implement a cache. That said: Only you can decide on how to implement session storage (in-proc will be lost the moment your instance gets reset/restarted), and whether you take on the associated risk associated with potential of losing session data.

Comment: Also it may cause unequal traffic distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Sticky sessions (Session-affinity) for ASP.net applications are configured using State Servers. You will have to run State Service (startup task or service). If you are using web roles, it is recommended to use Azure In-Role cache. Here is the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cache/cache-dotnet-how-to-use-in-role

As David said, Radis cache is not the 'only' alternative.

Trust it helps.

Comment: From that link, "Azure In-Role Cache service will be retired on November 30, 2016. Our recommendation is to use Azure Redis Cache".